# $\hom_R(A,B)$ is finitely generated if $R$ is noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

This is part of an exercise I'm doing, from Rotman Introduction to homological algebra.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $A$ and $B$ be finitely generated $R$-modules.

Then if $R$ is noetherian, prove that $\hom_R(A, B)$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

I'm stuck on it, any hint ?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $A$ is finitely generated, there is an epimorphism of modules of the form
$$R^n\rightarrow A$$
for some $n$. This induce a monomorphism
$$\text{hom}_R(A,B)\rightarrow \text{hom}_R(R^n,B)\text{.}$$
What can you say about $\text{hom}_R(R^n,B)$?

Comment: If you need a more extensive hint, please say me.

Comment: @user26857 If he/she is learning homological algebra, it is an standard result in any course of commutative algebra that $B^n$ is notherian when $B$ is. I am giving the connection between $\text{hom}_R(A,B)$ and something that can be known.